# Enabling methods in template class based on template type

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

I'm writing an template integer wrapper class where I'd like to provide an assigment operator based on template parameter type of the class:

```
template<typename IntType>
class secure_int {
public:
  // enable only if boost::is_signed<IntType>
  secure_int &operator=(intmax_t value) {
   // check for truncation during assignment
  }

  // enable only if boost::is_unsigned<IntType>
  secure_int &operator=(uintmax_t value) {
   // check for truncation during assignment
  }
};
```

Because operator= is not a member template, then SFINAE with boost::enable_if_c wouldn't work. What are working options for providing such feature?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use template specialization?

```
template<typename IntT>
struct secure_int {};

template<>
struct secure_int<intmax_t>
{
  secure_int<intmax_t>& operator=(intmax_t value)
  { /* ... */ }
};

template<>
struct secure_int<uintmax_t>
{
  secure_int<uintmax_t>& operator=(uintmax_t value)
  { /* ... */ }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it into a member template and default the parameter to void in C++11. If you don't have a compiler that supports that feature, then specialization is your only option.

Comment: I went that way to see if it is a working solution, but my company has not switched to C++11 yet.